# Calculating pairwise spatial distances in periodic 2D lattice

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

I've been searching in vain for a solution to compute spatial distances between discrete, equidistant square sites on a lattice of periodic/wrapped edges. For example, setting adjacent sites to be 2 units apart on 9x9 lattice:

```
m = 9
lattice = np.zeros((m,m))
for i in arange(0,6+1,3):
    for j in arange(0,6+1,3):
        lattice[i,j]=1

In  []: lattice
Out []: array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In  []: plt.imshow(lattice, origin='origin', cmap='binary', interpolation='none')
```

[image]
where the sites are annotated with indices and the red arrows indicate equidistances from site 0 (2 units), how can I create an array `sdist` that gives me the shortest pairwise distances between sites, i.e. `sdist[7,1]=2`, `sdist[2,6] = 2.8284`. The usual tool `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: by "wrapped" do you mean the matrices tile the 2D plane or a torus (Asteroids Video Game style)? Including the throgth corner cases?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I meant like a 2D plane, so not including corner cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `distance.cdist` accepts an arbitrary metric, provided as a callable, the problem is just in writing a function for your metric.

If it was wrapped distance between points p and q, that would be

```
def wrapped_euclidean_points(p, q):
    diff = np.abs(p - q)
    return np.linalg.norm(np.minimum(diff, m - diff))
```

where `m` is the size of the lattice (unfortunately `cdist` does not support passing extra parameters to the distance function, so `m` has to be taken from the larger scope.)

But in your case, you want minimal distances between squares of sidelength 1. What this means is that after computing the wrapped-difference vector `np.minimum(diff, m - diff)` we can reduce each of its components by 1, because, say, the smallest x-difference between points of two squares is 1 less than the x-difference between the centers of those squares. Of course this subtraction should not make the difference *negative*. 
So the function becomes

```
def wrapped_euclidean_squares(p, q):
    diff = np.abs(p - q)
    return np.linalg.norm(np.clip(np.minimum(diff, m - diff) - 1, 0, None))
```

where `clip` takes care of the case when two centers had the same x-coordinate or the same y-coordinate.

The rest is just two lines (not counting `from scipy.spatial import distance`):

```
coords = np.vstack(np.nonzero(lattice)).T
dist = distance.cdist(coords, coords, metric=wrapped_euclidean_squares)
```

Output for your example:

```
[[ 0.          2.          2.          2.          2.82842712  2.82842712       2.          2.82842712  2.82842712]
 [ 2.          0.          2.          2.82842712  2.          2.82842712       2.82842712  2.          2.82842712]
 [ 2.          2.          0.          2.82842712  2.82842712  2.       2.82842712  2.82842712  2.        ]
 [ 2.          2.82842712  2.82842712  0.          2.          2.          2.       2.82842712  2.82842712]
 [ 2.82842712  2.          2.82842712  2.          0.          2.       2.82842712  2.          2.82842712]
 [ 2.82842712  2.82842712  2.          2.          2.          0.       2.82842712  2.82842712  2.        ]
 [ 2.          2.82842712  2.82842712  2.          2.82842712  2.82842712       0.          2.          2.        ]
 [ 2.82842712  2.          2.82842712  2.82842712  2.          2.82842712       2.          0.          2.        ]
 [ 2.82842712  2.82842712  2.          2.82842712  2.82842712  2.          2.       2.          0.        ]]
```

Comment: I don't believe your wrapped distance function works for general lattice points, even 45 degree diagonal case like [1,1] to [7,7]

Comment: `wrapped_euclidean_squares([1, 1], [7, 7])` returns 2.828... which is sqrt(8). Seems right to me. What value did you expect?

Comment: sqrt(3) is the distance "thru the corner" [1,1]:[0,0]:[8,8]:[7,7]

Comment: That looks like it would be 3*sqrt(2) to me, which is what the function `wrapped_euclidean_points` would return for these points. And I explained the difference between point-to-point distance and square-to-square distance in my answer. Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: yes, my mistake, my example min distance would be sqrt(6), which doesn't equal sqrt(8) Alex __ wrapped_euclidean_squares([1, 1], [7, 7]) returns 2.828... which is sqrt(8)__

Comment: @Alex Incredible. A lot for me to learn by studying your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I tried to understand the request, my interpertaion is illustrated here

Instead of ones for the lattice points, I numbered them, starting from 1

I then 'augmented' the cell given in `lattice` by slicing and using `np.concatenate` to add half cells on each boarder of starting lattice
Yellow lines on the plot show cell boarders

Given starting lattice point label number, I find all instances in my 'fullLaug' array and calc squared Euclidean disatnce, and sort by it

Per the example I take the shortest and plot a line from the starting point `1` to the shortest distance instance of the each of the rest of the points in 'fullLaug' as well as printing the actual distance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

" create lattice, lattice points nonzero, incremtning count "

m = 9
pcnt = 0
lattice = np.zeros((m, m))
for i in range(0, 6+1, 3):
    for j in range(0, 6+1, 3):
        pcnt += 1
        lattice[i, j] = pcnt # lable lattice points with count

#print(*lattice, sep='\n')

"augment lattice with duplicated halves, up/down, left/right"

def halves(a):
    n = len(a)
    return a[:(n+n%2)//2-n%2], a[(n-n%2)//2+n%2:]


rightL, leftL = halves(lattice.T)
n = len(rightL)
cornerL = np.zeros((n, n))
rightL, leftL = rightL.T, leftL.T

rightLaug = np.concatenate((cornerL, rightL, cornerL), axis=0)
leftLaug = np.concatenate((cornerL, leftL, cornerL), axis=0)

lowL, upL = halves(lattice)

centerL = np.concatenate((upL, lattice, lowL), axis=0)

fullLaug = np.concatenate((leftLaug, centerL, rightLaug), axis=1)

"plot fully agumented lattice, yellow lines are boarders of cells"

plt.imshow(fullLaug, origin='origin', cmap='jet', interpolation='none')

plt.plot((n, n), (0, 2*n+m-1), 'y', (n+m-1, n+m-1), (2*n+m-1, 0), 'y')
plt.plot((0, 2*n+m-1), (n, n), 'y', (2*n+m-1, 0), (n+m-1, n+m-1), 'y')

#print(*zip(*np.where(fullLaug == 3)))


def distsq(a, b, n):
    """takes lattice point pcnt labels a, b
    finds a indices in lattice, offests to indices in fullaug
    finds all instances of b indices in fullaug
    calcs all a-b distances
    returns sorted list of distances, indices, a-a appended to start
    """
    a = list(*zip(*np.where(lattice == a)))
    a[0] += n; a[1] += n

    bz = zip(*np.where(fullLaug == b))

    ds = [[(a[0] - b[0])**2 + (a[1] - b[1])**2, [*b]] for b in bz]

    return [[0, a]] + sorted(ds, key=lambda x: x[0])

""" plot shortest distance lines from point a to each point in lattice
    fill dist_lattice"""

dist_lattice = np.zeros((m, m))
for i in range(1, pcnt + 1):
    dps = distsq(1, i, n)[0:2]
    dist_lattice[np.where(lattice == i)] = np.sqrt(dps[1][0])
    plt.plot(*zip(dps[0][1], dps[1][1]))

np.set_printoptions(precision=4, threshold=1000)
print(dist_lattice)

[[ 0.      0.      0.      3.      0.      0.      3.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 3.      0.      0.      4.2426  0.      0.      4.2426  0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 3.      0.      0.      4.2426  0.      0.      6.7082  0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
 [ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ]]
```